# How do I make a div to a Bootstrap drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I need to make a div as a dropdown and when clicking on it, 
the menu slides and shows its items.

I've tried to implement this but when clicking on the div it doesn't show 
it's items at all.

I've used this reference:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-examples

Here's the way I've implemented this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

```css
.top-bar-margin-top {
  margin-top: 43px;
  /*padding: 0;*/
}
.top-bar-margin-top a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 top-bar-margin-top">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="top-bar-small-title make-it-regular">item</span>
      <br />
      <span class="top-bar-app-links make-it-regular">Select Item</span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can it be solved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 2 things wrong here:

1. You're mixing both `data-*` attributes and JavaScript initialization, it should be either one or the other (maybe this isn't a real problem, but it is unnecessary and messy).
2. You haven't followed the example correctly, the dropdown trigger and contents need to both be contained within the div with class "dropdown".

Change the HTML to:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 top-bar-margin-top">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="top-bar-small-title make-it-regular">item</span>
      <br />
      <span class="top-bar-app-links make-it-regular">Select Item</span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

No JS required (just include the bootstrap.js and it should do the rest).

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dpjpcfuy/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot apokryfos!

Comment: Super clean answer!

Comment: How do I make the drop down appear from the right.

https://jsfiddle.net/dpjpcfuy/110/  Thanks!!

Comment: @Nik this is completely unrelated to the original question . Perhaps it's worth asking a separate question or checking whether the [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar) does what you need

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `data-target` attribute

```
<ul class="no-bullets droppable-menu">
     <li><a href="#" data-target="#m-target-1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Our Story</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-target="#m-target-2" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Our Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

target is in the div

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="m-target-1">

    ... content in your div            

</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="m-target-2">

        ... content in your div            

    </div>
```

and remove

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

from your JS code. This should work!